# Eclipse Android Text Scroll Issue

Tags: android, scroll

I use this simple command to make my TextView scrollable:

```
mainText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

The problem is the following:

if the user scrolls it down, and the text changes, it stays scrolled, so you need to scroll up. Any way to "reset" the scroll every time it changes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the inherited method scrollTo(x,y) to set the postition when you update the data
i.e.

```
mainText.scrollTo(0,0);
```